# Can't get response from Zendesk ticket API with JavaScript fetch

Tags: javascript, zendesk-api

I'm trying to create an HTML form which creates a ticket in Zendesk. The form will also include a file upload.
Right now I'm able to create the ticket with the API, but I can't get the response from the API call. I need the response to get the ticket id from the created ticket. I can use this id the attach the uploaded file to the ticket.
But like I said, I can't retrieve the response.

Code:

```js
function createTicket() {      
    var id;
    var easyWalker = $("#choose_product option:selected").html();
    var batchNumber = document.getElementById("batch_number").value;
    var color = document.getElementById("color").value;
    var firstName = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
    var lastName = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
  
    console.log("creating ticket");

    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic " + auth);
    myHeaders.append("Cookie", "__cfruid=f6f220be875e5825ba2ea5650a7a58d04ceb1299-1695207433; _zendesk_cookie=BAhJIhl7ImRldmljZV90b2tlbnMiOnt9fQY6BkVU--0bf2100788cb010d0183feca16aaf88ccaf719ca");
    
    var raw = JSON.stringify({
            "ticket": {
                "subject": "New Easywalker Warranty Registry from " + firstName + " " + lastName,
                "description": 
                  "Product: " + easyWalker + "\n" +
                  "Batch Number: " + batchNumber + "\n" +
                  "Color: " + color + "\n" +
                  "Name: " + firstName + " " + lastName + "\n" +
                  "Email: " + email + "\n" +
                  "Phone Number: " + phone,
                "requester": {
                  "name": firstName + " " + lastName,
                  "email": email
                }
            }
        });
    
    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: raw,
      redirect: 'follow'
    };
    
    fetch("https://easywalkersupport.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets", requestOptions)
      .then(response => id = response)
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));

    return id;
}
```

I know that response isn't the id, but I don't know what property I need to access to do so, because I can't see the result. Previously I used console.log(result) but nothing was displayed in the console.

Currently I'm getting this error in the console: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://easywalkersupport.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 201.`, although the ticket is created in Zendesk.

Could someone help me with a solution and an example of an implementation of the given solution?

Thanks in advance!

Ivan

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? Have you checked the browser network view to see if the Zendesk fetch returned anything?

Comment: The ticket is created in Zendesk but I get a CORS error in the console.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought. You can't get response info from another site unless it allows it (via CORS response headers), and apparently Zendesk doesn't.

Comment: That is weird, because when I try to make the API call with Postman, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: That's because Postman does not care about CORS headers. Browsers do.

Comment: Ah, that's good to know, thanks! Do you have any suggestions? Or is there nothing I can do? As far as I know this should be possible (at least, that's what zendesk sais)

Comment: Generally people do that from within their own server applications. Your server code will be able to interact with Zendesk and not care about CORS. The whole cross-origin thing is to prevent browser hacking.

Comment: Hi. Even if you can get the response from the API call, your code needs to convert the body to access the result. As you are using fetch api, use the .json() method inside then, for example: const data = response.json()

Answer (score 0):

You are using the endpoint `/api/v2/tickets`, which is intendend for agents and admins. See: [Tickets vs Requests](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/ticketing/managing-tickets/tickets-vs-requests-apis-how-to-select-the-right-option-for-your-project/)

For creating a custom HTML I would recommend that you use the endpoint `/api/v2/requests`, which is intended to be used by end-users. See: [Create Request](https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/ticketing/tickets/ticket-requests/#create-request)

As a final recommendation, what I usually do on projects that need a custom HTML form, it to have a middleware server between the website and the Zendesk API. Zendesk have this tutorial explaining how to make this work using Node.js or Python. [Custom Ticket Form Web App](https://developer.zendesk.com/documentation/ticketing/managing-tickets/building-a-custom-ticket-form-with-the-zendesk-api/)